# How can I run multiple Jackrabbit instances or repositories under one Tomcat server?

Tags: tomcat

I've got one instance of Jackrabbit 2.6.5 running under Tomcat 7.0.42 on Ubuntu 13.10 by dropping the WAR into Tomcat's webbapps folder as jackrabbit.war.

If I copy the war file to jackrabbit2.war, it starts up a second instance at host:8080/jackrabbit2, but it seems to share the same configuration (and hence repo storage) as, if I create a workspace in one instance, my repo browser shows it as present in both.

Note that I've revised WEB-INF/web.XML to point bootstrap-config to /opt/jackrabbit/bootstrap.properties (for both Repository and RepositoryStartup), and bootstrap.properties to with repository.home=/opt/jackrabbit and repository.config=/opt/jackrabbit/repository.xml  for the first instance and made the same changes (but to /opt/jackrabbit2) for the second instance - so both repos should be using their own config and locations?

The reason for running multiple repos (whether under one or many Jackrabbit instances) is so that I can configure them with different backends for testing.

Is there any way of doing this? Do I need to tell Tomcat these are not the same app, or something? Or have I missed something in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was a dud question - you can run multiple repos absolutely fine, either by using multiple copies of the jackrabbit webapp or by using virtual hosts (there may be other ways). Part of the confusion lay in the way tomcat spreads its configuration over multiple files, and copies workspace config from repository.xml to workspace.xml when each workspace is created, thereby freezing the config of each workspace.